# Convert JMeter reports to JUnit reports

Tags: junit, jmeter, azure-pipelines

How can I convert JMeter reports to JUnit reports. There are tools like VSTS that knows how to integrate JUnit reports, but not JMeter reports (though they can run JMeter).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I created a XSLT to transform XML JMeter reports into JUnit ones: https://gist.github.com/beradrian/9933070a26d7c72ce67ee26242ed5a2b.

Comment: is there any steps on how to use this?

Comment: Just use your preferred XSLT engine to do this. It's basically converting a XML (JMeter report) to another XML (JUnit report) using the XSLT that I wrote.

Comment: There are also XML editors supporting XSLT or XSLT libraries to integrate in your code. It all depends on how you want to do it.

Answer (score 5):

You can run your JMeter test via [Taurus tool](http://gettaurus.org/), it has [JUnit XML Reporter](http://gettaurus.org/docs/Reporting/#JUnit-XML-Reporter) subsystem so it will be possible to get results in JUnit format in addition to normal .jtl result files.

Comment: The thing is that requires installation of a new tool.